# Check if dynamically added TextEdit has text in it Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm overriding the `onFocusChanged` to pinpoint the TextEdit that just lost focus. The point is to remove this TextEdit if it doesn't have any text in it. The problem is that the `if((EditText...` is not valid. I get `cannot resolve method 'getText()'`. I've tried casting it to tell that it's a EditText view.

`listItemsView` is the id of the LinearLayout and listItems is an ArrayList of EditText.

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) {

        int removeCurrent = listItems.indexOf(this)+1;
        // code to execute when EditText loses focus
        if((EditText)view.getText().equals("")) {

        }
        listItemsView.removeViewAt(removeCurrent);
        listItems.remove(removeCurrent);
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
if((EditText)listItemsView.getChildAt(removeCurrent).getText().equals(""))
```

And got the same result.

Comment: are you getting any value from (EditText)view.getText().toString() ?

Comment: It's not a valid method so it won't compile.

Comment: you mean edittext.gettext().tostring() is not a valid !!! ,it might be casting problem in your view,let us show full source of your adapter file.

Comment: Yeah it was a casting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to cast a value to a type, you do this:

```
(T)V
```

Where `T` is the type you want to cast to, and `V` is the value.

So far so good?

In your code,

```
(EditText)view.getText().equals("")
```

What is `V` and what is `T`? The answer might surprise you! `T` is obviously `EditText`, but `V` here is actually `view.getText().equals("")`!

In other words, you did not cast `view` to `EditText`. That's why the compiler can't find a method named `getText`. To tell the compiler to specifically cast `view`, add parentheses:

```
((EditText)view).getText().equals("")
```

Comment: Ah thanks! had to add toString after getText() to get the text.

Comment: @Emsal If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!